# Set form control holding multple selection in mat select to null

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, multipleselection, mat-select

Mate select has the feature of multiple selection. How to set null the form control value that is holding those multiple selection... Here in my case it is not working...

```
reset(){
    this.form.reset();
    return false
    }

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      category: [''],
});
```

**In template**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>Categories</mat-label>
                        <mat-select formControlName="category" multiple>
                          <mat-select-trigger>
                        <mat-icon matPrefix *ngIf="f['category'].value" (click)="clearCategory($event)"
                         class="icon" title="clear">clear</mat-icon>
                            {{f['category'].value ? f['category'].value[0] : ''}}
                            <span *ngIf="f['category'].value?.length > 1" class="example-additional-selection">
                              (+{{f['category'].value.length - 1}} {{f['category'].value?.length === 2 ? 'other' : 'others'}})
                            </span>
                          </mat-select-trigger>
                          <mat-option #allSelectedCategories (click)="toggleAllCategories()" [value]="0" >
                              All Categories (default)
                          </mat-option>
                          <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categories" 
                          (click)="toggleOnCategory(allSelectedCategories.viewValue)"
                          [value]="category">{{category}}</mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                      </mat-form-field>
```

on click the reset button values of category not cleared from form value but only from input field

```
 <button type="reset" mat-raised-button (click)="reset()" 
                      style="margin-right: 5px;">
                        Reset
                    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the button to clear all multi-select check boxes?  In other words, the user checks a few then you want to reset them to not checked?

Try this:

selectedOptions = [];

Update: sorry about that, you would have needed something like:

```
<mat-selection-list [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions" [compareWith]="compareFunction">
```

Answer (score 0):

`.reset()` does not clear values from form controls. [It resets the values of the controls to what they were before changes were made](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset). This works the same in Angular (in all variations, e.g. `FormControl.reset()`, `NgForm.resetForm()`, etc.) and in pure JavaScript.